# Periodic solution of differential equation $y′=f(y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

> Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R^2)$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb R^2$ $f(kx)=k^2f(x)$ for $k\in \mathbb R$
> Show that any periodic solution of $y′=f(y)$ is constant.

My attempt :

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $g$ a periodic solution defined by $g_{\lambda}(t) = \lambda g(\lambda t)$.

With Cauchy-Lipshitz theorem $g_{\lambda}$ and $g$ do not intersect for $\lambda \neq 1$ and for $\lambda >1$, if $g(0)>0$ we have $g_{\lambda} > g.$
but I do not see how to continue.

Comment: Please show your working so far :)

Comment: @Julien If you wish to merge your accounts, there are [instructions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to do so in the help center.

Comment: It is already made. But thank you.

Comment: Can you write down explicitly what you mean by periodic?

Comment: Hi, a periodic function like $f(e^{i \theta}) = f(e^{i (\theta+ \pi)})$ or I do not understand the question.

Comment: Let $f(x) = |x| x$. Then $y(x) = |x|^3/3$ is a periodic solution. But perhaps I misunderstand your condition on $f$. Is it supposed to be $\forall x \in {\bf R}^2 \forall k \in {\bf R} f(kx) = k^2f(x)$?

Comment: f is homogeneous of degree 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose first that $f(x) \neq 0$ when $x \neq 0$ and consider the map $S^1 \to S^1$ given by restricting $f$ to the set $|x| = 1$ and normalizing it. Because $f(x) = f(-x)$, the degree of this map is even. This means there are no periodic solutions $y$ that wind around origin, since those have degree 1.

If $f(x) = 0$ for some $x \neq 0$ then $f(kx) = 0$ for all $k \in {\bf R}$. So in this case there can't be any periodic solution winding around origin either.

Consider now the map $\pi_C : {\bf R}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to S^1$ given by projecting to the unit circle around origin. The above discussion tells us that $\pi_C \circ y : S^1 \to S^1$ is not surjective. But it is continuous, so its image is connected and therefore an interval in $S^1$. Denote this interval by $[a,b]$ and let $x \in y(S^1)$ be one of the points in the pre-image of $a$, that is $\pi_C x = a$. Denote by $X$ the closure of the connected component containing $x$ in $\pi_C^{-1}(a)$. This is an interval $[c,d]$ lying in the half-ray with the slope $a$. Consider now points $s, t \in y(S^1)$ that are close to $c$ and $d$ respectively and both lying on a half-ray with the slope $a + \epsilon$. Because they belong to the same half-ray, $t = ks$ for some $k \in {\bf R}$ and so the vectors $f(t) = k^2 f(s)$ are linearly dependent. But this impossible since the curve $y$ must have distinct tangent vectors at $s$ and $t$ -- one leans towards the half-ray with slope $a$ and the other away from it.

Comment: A small gap in this answer: the map $\pi_C \circ y$ can be surjective. But the half-ray argument still works, it's just little harder to locate the set $X$ which will exist whenever the winding number is $0$. I'll update the answer later, but here's the sketch: every half-ray intersects $y(S^1)$ in even number of points (counted with multiplicity). It must sometimes happen that some of those points merge into a double-point or an interval like $X$, otherwise there would have to some self-crossings or the curve would have a disconnected image.

Comment: thank you for your time, what does this mean $S^1$ ? unit sphere ? i do not understand what do you mean by : the degree of this map is even?

Comment: @Julien: yes, by $S^1$ I mean circle, either by itself or embedded in ${\bf R}^2$ as a unit circle or as the image of $y$, which I denote by $y(S^1)$. The degree of a map is basically how many times it wraps around the circle. E.g. the complex maps $z^n$ restricted to the unit circle have degree $n$, identity has degree one and so do all the embeddings of $S^1$ into $\bf R^2$.

Comment: I'll try it again with your response,Thank you!